# Non-root user having /root as $HOME

Tags: linux, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have the following entry in `/etc/passwd` file:

```
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
```

However, when I `sudo -su daemon` the `$HOME` seems to be set to `/root`:

```
[root@sbecby07 ~]# sudo -su daemon 'echo $USER $HOME'
daemon /root
```

I've already done `sudo usermod -d /sbin daemon` to change it back to `/sbin` but it's still pointing to `/root`.

I also don't find any $HOME-modifying line in `/etc/profile`.

Where should I look further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between `sudo -s` and `sudo -i`.

You're using `sudo -s`, which does not set the target user's resources, including the `$HOME` variable.  It just loads the user's shell.

`sudo -i` runs the shell as a login shell, which is like a new session, including setting the right home as well as loading `.profile` and `.login`.

See `man sudo` for details.

---

#### Demonstration

You can see the differences between `sudo -s` and `sudo -i` here:

```
root@node51 [~]# sudo -s -u deltik echo '$USER' '$HOME'
deltik /root
root@node51 [~]# sudo -i -u deltik echo '$USER' '$HOME'
deltik /home/deltik
```

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, sudo -i is the correct command to actually open a login shell for that user, which then has the correct environment including $HOME set.

However, if you really want to do that, you need to have a valid login shell defined in you /etc/passwd, so you should change that /sbin/nologin to - for example - /bin/bash first.